# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: debugLevel

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Alright, I've been going thru posts left and right trying to figure out this error.. I've managed to fix a few errors, but this is just driving me nuts.. it has almost no information.. or atleast none that makes any sense to me.

```
  D/dalvikvm(431): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.hyperlinkup.manglerbt/lib/libventrilo_interface.so 0x405156c8
D/dalvikvm(431): Added shared lib /data/data/com.hyperlinkup.manglerbt/lib/libventrilo_interface.so 0x405156c8
D/dalvikvm(431): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.hyperlinkup.manglerbt/lib/libventrilo_interface.so 0x405156c8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(431): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 61K, 53% free 2565K/5379K, external 1027K/1038K, paused 89ms
W/dalvikvm(431): No implementation found for native Lcom/hyperlinkup/manglerbt/VentriloInterface;.debuglevel (I)I
D/AndroidRuntime(431): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(431): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(431): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: debuglevel
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.hyperlinkup.manglerbt.VentriloInterface.debuglevel(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.hyperlinkup.manglerbt.ServerList.onCreate(ServerList.java:96)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process(431): Sending signal. PID: 431 SIG: 9
```

I'm trying to rework the Mangler app to use Bluetooth recording (via startBluetoothSco), but I want to make sure the original is working before incorporating the bluetooth functionality.. Any help I can get on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

edit: thinking maybe my issue is with jni_wrappers.c.. first 3 #include's are unresolved.. original build was on linux system it would appear, so it's looking for jni.h, stdint.h and ventrilo3.h

Comment: So my jni_wrappers.c file includes <stdint.h>, <jni.h>, and a third file that I have.. all 3 are coming up as unresolved.. I'm on a Windows System... am I pretty much SOL right now until I can get the better linux system atleast VM'd on here?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in the Logcat Stacktrace itself

**No implementation found for native Lcom/hyperlinkup/manglerbt/VentriloInterface;.debuglevel (I)I D/AndroidRuntime(431): Shutting down VM**

There is a Native method called `debuglevel` in `VentriloInterface`. You have not implemented that method. So, the VM throws `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Comment: I must be missing something then..VentriloInterface.debuglevel(VentriloDebugLevels.V3_DEBUG_INFO); in Serverlist.java.. I comment it out, get another error.. comment that one out, and I get the app to start, but it still breaks.. Perhaps I'm just too tired right now to really figure it out, but it seems there is more to it.

Comment: I think that this is the solution we can provide you using the details provided.